# Biztalk EDI - View final outbound X12 interchange

Tags: biztalk, edi, x12

I've been running Biztalk 2004 with the Covast EDI accelerator since 2004.  I'm currently upgrading to Biztalk 2013 R2 and having difficulty viewing the final outbound interchange document for an X12 document. My final destination is an AS2EDISend port.

I can see the interchange information (sender/receiver/control ID) in the report "EDI Interchange and Correlated ACK status".  I can see more information by viewing the "Interchange Status and ack Details" screen.  I can view the transaction set.  I can view the transaction set details and from there get the final transaction set (ST to SE segment) in raw ASCII format.

But I can't see the raw final outbound interchange complete with the ISA/GS segments.

I do have tracking turned on and when I look at the tracked message events, I can see receive/send events for the AS2EDI pipeline.  When I look at the message on the receive event, it's the XML representation of the transaction set.  When I look at the message on the send event, it's already been AS2 encoded and I'm unable to view the raw ASCII EDI file complete with ISA/GS segments.

Am I missing something?  Is there somewhere else to look?  Will I have to configure a secondary send port which only does EDISend and write to my filesystem and maintain/archive that information myself?

Comment: Using Biztalk 2013 R2 inside the AS2 agreement there is a section which says "Sender Message Tracking (NRR)"  if I enable that and wait for the next AS2 transmission, I now have a right click option in the AS2/MDN status which says "View Message Decoded Format" which gives me exactly what I'm looking for.  The full interchange including all transaction sets and interchange information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISA and GS segments will be promoted into the context of the message, as ISA_String and GS_String respectively.  The individual segment values are also promoted as ISA01, ISA02, etc. and GS01, GS02, etc.

Since you're using AS2, I think the easiest solution would be to create a send port group, use your existing send port with AS2 in it, and another SendPort with EdiSend using the FILE adapter.  Another option would be to add a custom pipeline component in the Encode stage that would archive the results from the EDI Assembler - which would be more efficient but more work as well.

Comment: I am unable to see those properties in the context of the batched message.  The transactions are batched.  The batch is released.  My AS2EDI Port receives the batch.  On the receive event of the port, it's XML.  On the send event of the port, it's encrypted payload.  The EDI assembly happens between those two steps and appears to be out of sight from me.  Context properties available are related to the AS2 Assembly.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I missed that bit.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want to see the interchange message for testing/develop propose, Put the send port to stop state, the message in this port will suspend. then you can view/save the message in admin console.

if you need a solution to "see" the interchange message in operation level. a second send port is an option.